# Can I use a second router on my network to isolate certain computers?

Tags: networking, router, malware

Ok, right now I have one router that I use for everything. It is plugged directly into my modem. My brother keeps on getting infected with malware no matter how many precautions I set up. He won't switch to linux because he can't play certain games.

Can I isolate his computer and consoles using a second router connected to the main router? I have a second router used solely as a switch but it has full access to the network.

I tried getting him to use the guest network feature through wifi but he complains about it being slow compared to the wired speeds.

Comment: Is the router configurable?

Comment: yes, currently the second router has DHCP off so it is acting as a switch

Comment: Sure bit his computer being infected isn't a security risk provided your computer is closed off from it by disabling network file sharing

Comment: Last time he got infected his computer started slamming one of the linux machines I have, but the firewall blocked everything. I don't know, I guess I am paranoid something is going to happen.

Answer (score 1):

You could be on 1 subnet and have him on a second subnet and the traffic would be isolated.  The traffic would still have to pass through the your router, but it offers some protection. A vlan would be even more protection, but I doubt your router has that.

Does either switch/router support the OpenWRT,Tomato, or other open source firmware?

Using these firmware you have access to iptables.

If you are on say subnet 192.168.1.1/24 and your brother 192.168.5.1/24

You can write a rules that DROPS all traffic from 5.1/24 aimed at 1.1/24.

If the main router had it you could also do this.

```
eth0 internet
eth1 your stuff
eth2 your stuff
eth3 brother's router
```

if source is eth3 and destination is not eth0 DROP

iptables -A FORWARD -i eth3 ! -o eth0 -j DROP
an additional rule for the INPUT,OUTPUT, and maybe one for the pre-routing CHAIN will probably be required.

Comment: I know the second router I have supports DD-WRT and OpenWRT. I even had gargoyle on it at one point. The main router however has some issues with both due to a flash chip or something like that. For the subnet thing, do I have to enable DHCP and then use LAN TO WAN? I can try that.